# Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'

Tags: python, django

1 I have a problem with my code when I want signup error to appear Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User' , I try a solution of other questions the same as Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'members.customer' but all of them asking to replace User = User = get_user_model() but I am not use any User in my code or I dont know where I used that.I'm new in django, python, js and etc so if my question is silly to forgive me.

Error:

> **AttributeError at /accounts/signup/ Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'users.User'**

**Setting.Py**:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'users.backends.EmailBackend',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'avatar',
    'homepage',
    'products',`enter code here`
    #user part
    'users',
]
```

**user/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class User(AbstractUser):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        pass
```

**accounts/models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.conf import settings
User= settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class Profile(models.Model):
    """
    Define model for user profile with one-to-one relationship with User table.
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    #country = CountryField(blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

# Define signals to update user profile whenever we create/update User model.       
@rece
iver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    Create Profile object whenever new User object is created.
    """
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Update Profile object whenever new User object is updated.
    """
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: Did you try to add this custom user model ***after*** your initial migrations?

Answer (score 0):

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'users',
]
```

> user/models.py:

This should be `users`.

Remove:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

From `accounts/models.py`.

Answer (score 0):

just try to add this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` at the end of settings.py file...

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code, you are still using the old User model when you have created a new Custom user model. In my case, I was using the old User model in forms which I did not look at first, that was my causing this error for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).