# Django Manager isn't available

Tags: python, django, registration

AttributeError at /register/
Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'accounts.Account'
I'm trying to create a registration form but getting the AttributeError.
How can to avoid the error?

Here is the code in of my custom model in
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    email                   = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username                = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined             = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login              = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    about                   = models.TextField(('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    is_admin                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active               = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser            = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
    from .forms import *
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    
def register_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = CreateUserForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=True)
        user.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'btn_label':'Register',
        'title':'Register'
    }
    return render(request, 'auth/auth.html', context)
```

I updated the setting.py file and set the following link to the Account model in accounts app
settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
```

Traceback

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /register/
Exception Value: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'accounts.Account'
```

Comment: Please share the *full* traceback.

Comment: Atteched the Traceback

Comment: @IvanVorobyev what is `CreateUserForm`? Can you show it's code?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem.
I had to inherite the `UserCreationForm` as `CreateUserForm`.



`from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ['username', 'email','password1','password2']`



Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310159/manager-isnt-available-auth-user-has-been-swapped-for-users-user